# How to replace fragment by checking userinfo list

Tags: android

Currently I am in `settingsfragment` and i have another Fragment called `ProfileFragment`. Now the problem is, by userinfo list i need to replace fragmnet like. If userinfo==null i should be in `settingFragment` or i should be in `ProfileFragment`.

```
if(userinfolist == null ){
        //login screen
        FragmentTransaction ft= getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.main_frame,settingsFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }else{
        //setting screen
        FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.main_frame,profileFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

But when I execute the code I am getting stuck.

Comment: userinfolist is arraylist.

Comment: @AndroidTeam is right. Basic java mistake...

Answer (score 1):

if your userinfo list is arraylist then used below code and also make sure your both fragment are define ..
then used below code like  ..

```
        List<User> userinfolist = new ArrayList<>();
    SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
    ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
    if (userinfolist.isEmpty()) {
        //login screen
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.main_frame, settingsFragment);
        ft.commit();
    } else {
        //setting screen
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.main_frame, profileFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Now I am getting a different error `stack=java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB` because I of this line `SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();` as i said I am already in SettingFragment only

Comment: SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment(); this line only example if you already created then not create again.

Answer (score 0):

You can typecast the layout in which the fragment is getting pushed and then clear the views of the layout using `layout.removeAllViews();`,and then do the rest for attaching a fragment,but by default you need to attach something i guess

Answer (score 0):

You can create a common method to replace fragments which will be more efficient like below method

```
   public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    }
```

Depending upon your condition, you can call fragment. In your case if userinfolist is a List then you can use below code.

```
 if(userinfolist!=null&&userinfolist.size()>0)

    replaceFragment(new profileFragment(), false);
    else
        replaceFragment(new SettingFragment(),false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code piece, as initializing FragmentManager & FragmentTransaction once is sufficient.

```
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

    List<User> userinfolist = new ArrayList<>();

    if (userinfolist == null) { 
        SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame,settingsFragment);

    } else {
        ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame,profileFragment);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```